# Sort ObservableList from high to low - javafx

Tags: javafx

Is there any way to sort a ObservableList based on the values from high to low?

Say I have a

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data> data;
```

containing a String and a Double. I want the list sorted based on the Double from highest to lowest values. The reason I want this is because charts look way better if their values are shown from the highest to the lowest.

I have something like this now:

```
sortedData = new SortedList<>(data);
sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(mycomparatorProperty());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Comparator`, compare by the Y value, and then reverse the order:

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(XYChart.Data<String,Double>::getYValue).reversed());
```

This will sort your collection as intented.

Or you can return a new collection:

```
List<XYChart.Data<String,Double>> sortedData = 
    data.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(XYChart.Data<String,Double>::getYValue).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT**

For the sake of clarity, this is a full sample:

```
public class FXMain extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String,Double>> data = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new XYChart.Data("P1",200d),
                    new XYChart.Data("P2",150d),
                    new XYChart.Data("P3",250d));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button"Sort data!");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
           ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String,Double>> data2 = 
                data.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.
                           comparing(XYChart.Data<String,Double>::getYValue).reversed())
                    .peek(System.out::println)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(()->FXCollections.observableArrayList()));
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should specify the type of arguments for `Data`: `private final ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String,Double>> data`.

Comment: but then ".collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> FXCollections.observableArrayList()));" fails

Comment: I actually gets this error: Comperator<Data<String,Double>> cannot be converted to Comperator<? super data> on your first approach.

Comment: I'm editing my answer with my class, so you can see how I've done it.

Comment: I fixed it, changed to     .map(entry -> new XYChart.Data<String,Double>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> FXCollections.observableArrayList()));

Comment: Have a look at my code, I do directly `data.stream()`, not `data.entrySet()`... You didn't specify anything about a `map`!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63814/discussion-between-minihessel-and-jose-pereda).